# How can I undo the changes made by setting a private file system path?

Tags: 7, files

I was installing the demo module on D7. I wanted to create a snapshot to use the demo reset part of the module. It told me to set the private file system path. So I entered the directory where all my websites live. /var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/ . Inside that folder there is a folder by domain name for each domain in the subscription. Including the folder for the site where i changed the path.

Now all the websites that are contained on the subscription are broken. As you can imagine, I'm desperate to know how to undo whatever I did. I'm so confused as yto how it has effected the other websites. I thought it was just going to be used to store the snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

When I set the path to the directory that contained my actual site/s, it placed a .htaccess file restricting access. Being as that folder contained many Drupal sites, all sites seemed broken.

Deleting that .htaccess file in the folder I entered resolved the issue.